# How do I prevent ENOENT error while running `npm test` in my tfs build?

Tags: angular, testing, npm, tfs, build

I'm trying to run npm test in my tfs build, but I get everytime I get an ENOENT error:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run test
>
> npm ERR! path E:\Agents\agent_work\38\package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -4058
>
> npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Agents\agent_work\38\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

I followed [this tutorial of Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/05/17/integrating-angular-4-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/) to set up my build and I also included `npm cache clean`, because I read that if you get enoent during install that might fix it.

When I run `npm test` locally it works fine

Below are my config files.

This is karma.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js');
  config.set({

    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
        require('karma-webpack'),
        require('karma-sourcemap-loader'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-junit-reporter')
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        { pattern: 'spec.bundle.js', watched: false }
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        'spec.bundle.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    // webpack
    webpack: testWebpackConfig,

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
    junitReport: {
        outputDir: '',
        outputFile: 'test.xml'
    }
  })
}
```

This is spec.bundle.js:

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

import 'rxjs';

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

var testContext = require.context('./src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

function requireAll(requireContext) {
    return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicated that npm test command cannot find the "package.json" file. Please make sure that your package.json file is uploaded into source control and downloaded during the build process and you configured the correct path to the package.json file (Working folder with package.json) for npm task in your build definition.

Comment: I didn't target the folder that contained the karma config, after I targeted that folder it worked.